# Trying to change MainPage but WebView on the new page fails to load site. But it is successful when I set it as the main page when application starts

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

My main page sends an API request in async way and then sets the main page to some other other page like this:

```
async private void GetContacts()
{
    try
    {
        activityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
        activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;

        var contacts = await Plugin.ContactService.CrossContactService.Current.GetContactListAsync();
        var contactsWithPhone = contacts != null && contacts.Count > 0 ?
        contacts.Where(c => c.Number != null && c.Number.Trim().Length > 0) : contacts;
        if (contactsWithPhone.Count() > 0)
        {
            Application.Current.Properties["FirstTime"] = false;
            activityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            List<NewsletterSubscriber> subscribers = new List<NewsletterSubscriber>();
            foreach (Plugin.ContactService.Shared.Contact contact in contactsWithPhone)
            {
                subscribers.Add(new NewsletterSubscriber() { Name = contact.Name != null && contact.Name.Trim().Length > 0 ? contact.Name : "Unknown", Phone = contact.Number });
            }
            SendContacts(subscribers);
        }
        Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    { throw; }
}

async void SendContacts(List<NewsletterSubscriber> subscribers)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    NewsletterSubscriberRoot newsletterSubscriberRoot = new NewsletterSubscriberRoot();
    newsletterSubscriberRoot.newsletterSubscribers = subscribers.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
    var content = newsletterSubscriberRoot.AsJson();
    try
    {
        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

These are my WebView events:

```
private void MainPage_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webView.Navigated += WebView_Navigated;
    webView.Navigating += WebView_Navigating;
    webView.Source = "https://appsoln.com";
}

private void WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
    activityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
    webView.IsVisible = false;
}
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    if (webView.CanGoBack)
    {
        webView.GoBack();
        return true ;
    }

    base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    return false;
}

private void WebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result == WebNavigationResult.Success)
    {
        activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
        activityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
        webView.IsVisible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayAlert("No connection (ER:CON2)", "Please check your Internet Connection.", "OK");
        var closer = DependencyService.Get<ICloseApplication>();
        closer?.closeApplication();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when the page containing WebView is set to main page when app starts it is opening the website fine. But when it is set from another main page then it goes into failure section of Navigated event. I am not seeing any exception in Output Window.

Comment: "when it is set from another main page" - what does this mean, exactly?  Where is the code that does this?  And what error response are you getting in WebNavigatedEventArgs?

Comment: @Jason I am assigning the `Application.Current.MainPage` property to the page containing the `WebView` from another page that is currently set as `MainPage`. I am not using the navigation to switch from one page to another.

Comment: again, And what error response are you getting in WebNavigatedEventArgs?

Comment: @Jason m getting `WebNavigationResult.Failure`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have to award this bounty to myself...If I could? ;)

I don't have the exact reason for this problem. If someone can tell me then it will be great.

What I did to solve this issue is that I removed `else {...}` part of `WebView_Navigated` event. Maybe WebView was trying again after failure and I was stopping it in else part by closing the application. The page takes time to load first time but it opens up eventually.